# Ruby on Rails: How to model Persons and Organisations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently building a Rails app where a **User** can have many **Persons** which in turn can have many **Projects**.

This works very well.

Now my problem is that some persons may belong to the same organisation while other persons may not belong to *any* organisation at all.

From what I've learnt so far, it would be good to move all the information pertaining the organisation into a separate table / model. (Please correct me, if I am wrong.) But what will happen then if a person does not belong to any organisation, i.e. is a private person?
How can all this be modelled in Rails?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your problem simply like, You have persons that may or may not belongs to an Organization. Now how will you set it up?

Now as you said you will move the *organization* related data in a separate table say `organizations`. And your `persons`(or `people`?) should contain a `organization_id`. **If the person doesnt belong to any organization**, then **it wil be simply null**. The model relationships will be somewhat like.

```
class Person < AR::Base
    belongs_to :organization
end

class Organization < AR::Base
    has_many :persons #or people?
end
```

I skipped the relations with `User` and `Project` model here. Please let me know if I missed any part of your question.

---

**Update:** *Based on your last comment* 
Lets list your scenarios:

1. A person and organization both can have address.
2. If a person doesnt belong to organization, then person may have his own address.
3. If he belongs to a Organization, then his address is actually the organization's address. Or might have own address.

If `address` is the only thing repeating in person and organization, then better move it in a separate table `addresses`.

**Organization:** `has_one :address`
**Person:** `has_one :address`

---

**Update 2:**

Since things are a bit conditional like

- If person belongs to organization then `person.address` will return the address of organization.
- Otherwise `person.address` will return its own address.

Then I would prefer the following way to keep it simple. Add a `current_address` *(or any preferred name)* method in your `Person` model.

```
def current_address
    return organization.address if organization
    return address
end
```

call `person.current_address` instead of `person.address` to go through the decisions.

Comment: Ok, thanks! This is actually what I've got so far. I was just wondering if this is a good way to model the data. I am still a bit worried about the amount of duplication in those two tables. E.g. a person will have an address and an organisation will have an address too. So where would I store that sort of data?

Comment: Is it only address or there are more columns that is repeating in both person and organization?

Comment: I think if it is address only, then better to make it a difference resource that can be availed by person or organization by `address_id`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Hello Samiron, I think when a person belongs to an organisation, only the organisation's address should be used. There's no need for a private address for that person then. What is the best way to model that in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

As I understood the situation:

[image: Situation]

You can translate this situation to rails in this way:

```
class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :persons
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organisation
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :persons
end
```

Comment: Yap, you understood it right. The drawing on my table looks the same, albeit not quite so neat and tidy ;-)

Comment: bro. what is the diff between person and user??

Answer (score 0):

try this may be it help you

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :organization
end
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :persons 
end
```

if person belongs to organization then in organization table person_id given else if person does not belongs to organization then in organization table person_id is nil. so that

```
in your console
-> product = @product.organization  
    # if person_id given then you get result
    # if person_id does not given then get null or blank
```

Comment: Thanks. You are basically saying the same as Samiron, so it seems I am on the right track here. Would you suggest another table to store address data then? Both persons and organisations will need an address.